# Unable to connect to internet with VirtualBox?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, wireless-networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine

Earlier, I was using multiple instances of Virtual Machines running Linux Ubuntu 14.04 on VirtualBox. They were working fine, with internet connectivity, etc. However, I then created a new Virtual Machine with the same settings, and now all of a sudden, all three of my virtual machines cannot connect to the internet. Currently, the network settings are at Bridged Adapter. The internet DOES work when I use NAT, but I need to use the Bridged Adapter setting for the project I am working on.

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling virtualbox, as well as uninstalling and reinstalling the VirtualBox Bridged Networking Driver, as well as turning off and turning on my host computer. Now I am completely out of ideas and it has been putting my work to a standstill. If you have any ideas on how to fix this problem, it would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the problem was due to the network on the other end. Thus, there wasn't really much I could do to fix it until the people at my office fixed the network connection.